# Selenium is giving " KeyError: 'sessionId' "

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, geckodriver

I am trying to start firefox using selenium but I am constantly getting

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 150, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 180, in start_session
    self.session_id = response['sessionId']
KeyError: 'sessionId'
```

The code I am trying to run is fairly simple

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Solutions I have tried:

1. Tried updating selenium(I was already using the latest one)
2. Updated the geckodriver to version 0.16.1
3. Tried changing the proxy settings

Nothing has worked till now.

Configuration I am using:
  geckodriver 0.16.1
, Mozilla Firefox 53
, Python 2.7
, Selenium 3.4.1
, I am on a Mac system(if that helps)

Comment: You need to give the path of your geckodriver binary inside the Firefox() method

Comment: @bad_deadpool I have also tried that but still not working. Please suggest something else

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading from Selenium 3.2.0 to 3.7.0 fixed this error for me. I have geckodriver 0.19.1

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not go in detail with this, sorry for that, but perhaps this might help you or give you a useful hint:

The following worked for me under Ubuntu 16.04:

If you run the pip installer as a normal user account, it seems to create these two directories with contents:

- ~/.local/lib
- ~/.local/selenium

Somehow it can't update this correctly, so these two directories seemed to contain an old version of selenium and needed libs in my setup. I have deleted both of these subtrees, so importing the webdriver is now using the system wide installation of selenium, which I upgraded as root via

```
sudo pip install -U selenium
```

It then worked for me. Please also have a look which python version your script is using, I needed to tell bash that I am using python2.7 via the shebang at the start of the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Perhaps this got to do with which python bindings you have installed, but I don't know, this is only a guess, as I told above, I did not go very deeply into it, but it might give you a hint.

I hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by downgrading a selenium server version to v.2.x.

I.e.  - instead of latest 3.x server version (selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar) i have tried latest 2.x. selenium server version (selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar)

My Python version:

```
Python 2.7.10
robotframework==2.9.2
robotframework-requests==0.4.5
requests==2.11.1
requests-oauthlib==0.7.0
requests-toolbelt==0.7.0
robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
selenium==3.0.1
requests-oauthlib==0.7.0
requests-toolbelt==0.7.0
```

Other software:

```
ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40
Google Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Windows 10`
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following happened(I am working on Kali Linux):

1. Uninstall Selenium:
   `pip uninstall selenium`
2. When I tried to reinstall selenium, I found that there was another instance of selenium(v 4.0) already present in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`
3. I removed both `selenium` and `selenium-4.0.0a1.egg-info` folders from the above mentioned directory(you need `sudo` permission for that).
4. I reinstalled `selenium` using `pip` and now the script works fine.